# RabbitMQ install error: Unrecognized option logic

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, erlang-otp

im trying to install RabbitMQ Server 3.12.0. Before i have installed compatible Erlang OTP 26.0 (have tried it also with 25.3).

In the setup i get the error message rabbitmq-service.bat install exited with code 1.

In the details ...\Erlang OTP\erts-14.0\bin\erlsrv: Unrecognized option logic.

I have also set the correct env variables for ERLANG_HOME and ERLANG_SERVICE_MANAGER_PATH.

Can someone help me pls?

Reinstalled several times.

Answer (score 0):

please test this:
Windows example:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html

Download versions that fit's together, i.e dependency's.
Example: RabbitMQ 3.12.1 and Erlang 26.0

1. Install Erlang, and when it is done, set environment system variable (it is version dependent), using above versions it is:

ERLANG_HOME=C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP

2. Then Install RabbitMQ
   https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html
3. Enable management plugins to frontend:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

There are also some configuration files to setup, but start with a successful install, so you know how that works.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html